# line + scatter chart in nvd3

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

Is it possible combine a line + scatter chart in nvd3.js without building a new model like is done with linePlusBarChart in the examples and code?   Or is this the only way that you can combine chart types?

Comment: did you find any solution to the problem. I also need the same! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

looke at this fiddle, gives you some idea

```
<code><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/7b48nzkm/">fiddle</a></code>
```

Comment: How do you compute the slope and intercept for regression?

Comment: This was exactly the solution that I was looking for - draw horizontal lines on my scatterChart without converting it to multiChart. The fiddle link helped.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [scatterPlusLineChart](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/scatterPlusLineChart.html) model, but I couldn't get it to work well for my data. If you just want to add markers to a line chart, see [Is an NVD3 Line Plot with Markers Possible?](/questions/13732971)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by changing the style for the path and points(circle) in the line chart for different series.